# embeding video objects in C# code

Tags: c#, video, embedding

I'm developing an app that plays some video files that should be copy protected. so I have to embed the videos in the code somehow to prevent from being copied. so do you guys have any idea what should I do?

P.S I'm sorry if the question is not accurate enough.

Comment: "DRM" is search term you are looking for... Probably the best thing you can do is to run away from the project. (Question is ether way too broad - if discussion DRM, or totally off-topic if you are asking whether to stay or run)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to encrypt (so no one can read it) then decrypt the file.

Comment: yeah, but when I decrypt the ecrypted file, it creates a video file that is copyable but what I want is a decrypted video OBJECT or something like that which exist on the memory not hard disk.